How to escape "and" in bibtex using authors with and in name
I would like to cite a UN report:
@misc{unesc2020,
    author = {United Nations Economic and Social Council},
    title = {Exploring space technologies for sustainable development and the benefits of international research collaboration in this context},
    pages = {16},
    ISBN = {E/CN.16/2020/3},
    URL = {https://unctad.org/system/files/official-document/dtlstict2021d1_en.pdf},
    year = {2020},
    type = {General Assembly}
}

Desired output in text:

However, utilizing space technologies such as EO data faces obstacles
such as lack of awareness of their benefits, constrained financial
resources, and gaps in technology and skills needed to adopt these
technologies ​(United Nations Economic and Social Council, 2020)​.

However, when I use use ~\cite{unesc2020}
This is the result:

However, utilizing space technologies such as EO data faces obstacles
such as lack of awareness of their benefits, constrained financial
resources, and gaps in technology and skills needed to adopt these
technologies ​(Council, 2020)​.


IMHO you also don't want to split the organization name into first name and last name. So you should use extra braces: {{United … Council}}. Unfortunately you've not shown a minimal working example with bibliography, so I cannot test if this really solves your issue, but I guess.
